# MousePressEvent sendEvent simulation to sub-widget in QT

Tags: c++, qt, message-queue

I have sub widget declared as below in MainWindow class I'm trying to send a mouse press event message to the sub object m_ss2dwdiget. The code works but invokes only the MainWindow event handler, not the m_ss2dwidget. So sub-widget handler is never getting invoked, what am I doing wrong here ?

```
class SSMainWind : public QMainWindow
{
  ....
  SS2DWidget* m_ss2dwidget;
  .....

}

void SSMainWind::on_actionTest_Item_triggered() {
    QMouseEvent event(QEvent::MouseButtonPress,pos, Qt::LeftButton, 0, 0);
    QApplication::sendEvent(this->m_ss2dwidget, &event);
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Did you try to ignore the event (`QEvent::ignore()`) in the MainWindow's event handler?

Comment: @vahancho I didn't get why should I really have to call the ignore procedure in MainWindow's event handler, but I've done without success, ignoring the event in the mainwindow event handler doesn't mean that it will be redirected to the child widget. I think the problem boils down to how and what intercepts the message not being transferred to child widget message queue mechanism.